# Script for sending e-mail

Tags: powershell, shell, scripting

I found one script online, which does quite simple work - sends e-mail to the specified address after the trigger is hit.

In the example below script should scan the path which I stated for the trigger which is: *#task*, then it expected that it should send e-mail with the text after *#td*.

It should be correct, but when I run it nothing happens - what I'm doing wrong?
I've got the following message in *powershell*:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IG5nB.png)

```
# Unregister-Event FileCreated
Unregister-Event FileChanged

# Email-settings
$loginuser = 'xxx@gmail.com'
$loginpassword = 'password;'
$smtpserver = 'smtp.gmail.com'
$smtpport = 587
$sendfrom = 'xxx@gmail.com'
$sendto = 'add.task.9270372.1523940684@todoist.net'

# Folder-settings
$folder = 'D:\Google Drive\Other\Nirvana' # Enter the root path you want to monitor.
$filter = '*.*'  # You can enter a wildcard filter here.

# In the following line, you can change 'IncludeSubdirectories to $true if required.
$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false; NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite' }

# Trigger-settings
$trigger = '#task'
$lookfor = '#td'
$replaceto = '#intasklist'

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Changed -SourceIdentifier FileChanged -Action {
    $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated
    $fileContent = (Get-Content $folder$name)
#    Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" -fore green
   if ($fileContent -match $trigger) {
    $fileContent | Select-String -Pattern ".*$($lookfor)" -AllMatches | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches } | ForEach-Object { $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $loginpassword -AsPlainText -Force; $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($loginuser, $secpasswd); Send-MailMessage -To $sendto -From $sendfrom  -Subject $_.Value -Body $name -SmtpServer $smtpserver -Port $smtpport -Credential $cred -UseSsl
    $fileContent | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $lookfor, $replaceto -replace " $($trigger)", '' -replace $trigger, '' } | Set-Content $folder$name }
    }}

# To stop the monitoring, run the following commands:
# Unregister-Event FileChanged
```

Comment: It's not supposed to do anything when you start it. You need to change a file in the watched path first.

Comment: There could be several files, cause it's the folder where I keep my markdown notes. So, the script should scan this folder and subfolder to find all the files with #td hash

Comment: @PalleDue There could be several files, cause it's the folder where I keep my markdown notes. So, the script should scan this folder and subfolder to find all the files with #td hash

Comment: What I mean is: You register a trigger, the script shouldn't do anything until it is triggered. The trigger is `FileChanged` so you need to change a file before anything happens.

Comment: So, it means that I just need to save the file I'm working with after that script would be executed. Anyway, that is not happening yet.

Comment: OK, then there is something wrong with the script: `(Get-Content $folder$name)` looks strange. You don't have a backslash after $folder. You should use `Join-Path` to join folder name and file name.

Comment: file name could be any name in that folder